# React Native: Dynamic state allocation inside a .map loop giving error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**My goal of this code:**

1. Render some view elements with a loop
2. Inside the loop, set the state
3. On clicking the elements, update that value

**Here is my code:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      maths: {},
    };
  }

  prepareMaths = function() {
    var count = 5;

    var updateMath = key => {
      var stateMaths = this.state.maths;
      stateMaths['position_' + key] = Math.random();

      this.setState({maths: stateMaths}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.maths);
      });
    };

    var stateMaths = this.state.maths;

    return [...Array(count)].map((options, key) => {
      stateMaths['position_' + key] = Math.random();
      this.setState({maths: stateMaths});

      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={key}
          onPress={() => updateMath(key)}
          style={{
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            marginRight: 20,
            marginBottom: 10,
            backgroundColor: 'green',
          }}>
          <Text>{this.state.maths['position_' + key]}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>{this.prepareMaths()}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**I'm getting this error with this code:**

[image]

I'm very confused. Because if I remove `setState...` code inside the loop, it's showing random maths naturally. But how? Since I'm using `this.state.maths['position_' + key]` on render. I really don't know how that data is generating.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't update state from the render function as that will trigger another render cycle.

Comment: @DrewReese, Thanks. But how can I do it? Please provide a solution.

Comment: What is the purpose of `this.setState({maths: stateMaths});` in the mapping loop?

Comment: This will save data to state for the first time, because that data is empty in constructor.

Comment: Yup, gave it all a deeper look and suspected it was an attempt to provide the "initial state" to render *something*.

Comment: Fixed with your answer. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. State mutations

   ```
   var stateMaths = this.state.maths; // <-- state
   stateMaths['position_' + key] = Math.random(); // <-- mutation!!
   ```
2. Updating state in render function causes rerender. `render` is a pure function with zero side-effects

   ```
   return [...Array(count)].map((options, key) => {
     stateMaths['position_' + key] = Math.random();
     this.setState({maths: stateMaths}); // <-- trigger rerender
   ```

## Solution

1. Factor `prepareMaths` and `updateMath` into standalone utility functions
2. Convert `maths` state to array
3. Use `componentDidMount` to initialize state
4. Use `componentDidUpdate` to log updated state
5. Move the JSX from `prepareMaths` to `render` function for mapping from state

Updated component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      maths: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.prepareMaths();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state.maths);
  }

  updateMath = (key) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      maths: prevState.maths.map((el, i) => (i === key ? Math.random() : el)),
    }));
  };

  prepareMaths = function () {
    const count = 5;

    this.setState({ maths: [...Array(count)].map(Math.random) });
  };

  render() {
    const { maths } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          {maths.map((value, key) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={key}
              onPress={() => this.updateMath(key)}
              style={{
                height: 100,
                width: 200,
                marginRight: 20,
                marginBottom: 10,
                backgroundColor: 'green',
              }}>
              <Text>{value}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[Expo Snack Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/react-native-dynamic-state-allocation-inside-a-map-loop-giving-error)